# Let $T$ be a normal and cyclic subgroup of a group$ G$. Show that every subgroup of $T$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have this algebra exercise to do.

> Let $T$ be a normal and cyclic subgroup of a group $G$. Show that every subgroup of $T$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Do you guys have any ideas on how I should do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $T$ is cyclic, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $T \cong \mathbb{Z}/n$. Thus, there is a unique cyclic subgroup of $T$ of order $d$ for every $d \vert n$ and every subgroup of $T$ is of this form.

So, let $N<T$ be a subgroup of $T$ of order $d$. Pick a generator $x$ of $N$. If you show that for every $g \in G$, $gxg^{-1}$ is of order $d$, you win since $gxg^{-1} \in T$ (since $T$ is normal) and the only elements of order $d$ in $T$ are in $N$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:If T is cyclic, two subgroups of T which have the same cardinal are equal.
Let H be a subgroup of T, and g in G, $gHg^{-1}\subset T$ and has the same cardinal than H, thus $gHg^{-1}=H$